# Code to populate Richfaces Tree component

Tags: jsf, tree, richfaces

**Code to populate Richfaces Tree component from properties file?**

Comment: Why this question is closed..can i know? Recently i tried for tree code.. struggled with it. I thought others won't have to get difficult with tree. so i pasted the tree code..so that others can use it..Is anything wrong behind this? I dont know the rules of stack overflow. Is it wrong to publish the code..If am wrong.. guide meee

Comment: I populated the tree component myself... it will be helpful for others. you can use that..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Tree.jsf:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="rich" uri="http://richfaces.org/rich"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="a4j" uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tree Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>

    <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" columnClasses="col1,col2">


            <rich:tree style="width:300px"
                nodeSelectListener="#{simpleTreeBean.processSelection}"
                reRender="selectedNode" switchType="client"
                ajaxSubmitSelection="true" value="#{simpleTreeBean.treeNode}"
                var="item">
            </rich:tree>


            <h:outputText escape="false"
                value="Selected Node: #{simpleTreeBean.nodeTitle}" id="selectedNode" />


        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

</f:view>
</body>
```

### **SimpleTreeBean.java**

package com.java.beans;

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Properties;


    import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlTree;
    import org.richfaces.event.NodeSelectedEvent;
    import org.richfaces.model.TreeNode;
    import org.richfaces.model.TreeNodeImpl;


    public class SimpleTreeBean {
              protected org.richfaces.component.UITree sampleTreeBinding;


              public org.richfaces.component.UITree getSampleTreeBinding() {
                        return sampleTreeBinding;
              }


              public void setSampleTreeBinding(
                                  org.richfaces.component.UITree sampleTreeBinding) {
                        this.sampleTreeBinding = sampleTreeBinding;
              }


              private TreeNode rootNode = null;
              private List<String> selectedNodeChildren = new ArrayList<String>();


              private String nodeTitle;


              private void addNodes(String path, TreeNode node, Properties properties) {
                        boolean end = false;
                        int counter = 1;


                        while (!end) {
                                  String key = path != null ? path + '.' + counter : String
                                                      .valueOf(counter);


                                  String value = properties.getProperty(key);
                                  if (value != null) {
                                            TreeNodeImpl nodeImpl = new TreeNodeImpl();


                                            nodeImpl.setData(value);
                                            node.addChild(new Integer(counter), nodeImpl);
                                            addNodes(key, nodeImpl, properties);
                                            counter++;
                                  } else {
                                            end = true;
                                  }
                        }
              }


              private void loadTree() {
                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                            .getResourceAsStream("com/xyz/resources/richtree.properties");
                        try {
                                  props.load(stream);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        rootNode = new TreeNodeImpl();
                        addNodes(null, rootNode, props);
              }


              public void processSelection(NodeSelectedEvent event) {
                        HtmlTree tree = (HtmlTree) event.getComponent();
                        nodeTitle = (String) tree.getRowData();
                        selectedNodeChildren.clear();
                        TreeNode currentNode = tree.getModelTreeNode(tree.getRowKey());
                        if (currentNode.isLeaf()) {


                                  selectedNodeChildren.add((String) currentNode.getData());
                        } else {
                                  Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, TreeNode>> it = currentNode
                                                      .getChildren();
                                  while (it != null && it.hasNext()) {
                                            Map.Entry<Object, TreeNode> entry = it.next();
                                            selectedNodeChildren.add(entry.getValue().getData().toString());
                                  }
                        }
              }


              public TreeNode getTreeNode() {
                        if (rootNode == null) {
                                  loadTree();
                        }
                        return rootNode;
              }


              public String getNodeTitle() {
                        return nodeTitle;
              }


              public void setNodeTitle(String nodeTitle) {
                        this.nodeTitle = nodeTitle;
              }

    }
```

---

### **richtree.properties :**

```
  1=Root Node 1
        2=Root Node 2
        3=Root Node 3
        1.1=Leaf 1.1
        1.1.1=Leaf 1.1.1
        1.1.2=Leaf 1.1.2
        1.1.3=Leaf 1.1.3
        1.1.4=Leaf 1.1.4
        1.1.5=Leaf 1.1.5
        2.1=Leaf 2.1
        2.1.1=Leaf 2.1.1
        2.1.2=Leaf 2.1.2
        2.1.3=Leaf 2.1.3
        2.1.4=Leaf 2.1.4
        2.1.5=Leaf 2.1.5
        3.1=Leaf 3.1
        3.1.1=Leaf 3.1.1
        3.1.2=Leaf 3.1.2
        3.1.3=Leaf 3.1.3
        3.1.4=Leaf 3.1.4
        3.1.5=Leaf 3.1.5
```

---

### **faces-config.xml**

```
 <managed-bean>             
            <managed-bean-name>simpleTreeBean</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.java.beans.SimpleTreeBean</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```